# PhoneGap or Native Android app?

Tags: android, cordova

I have iOS app ready and want to port to Android app. I use Facebook SDK with WebServices. App is relatively easier on graphics. What is recommendation?
Should I try PhoneGap or try to write native Android? What will be faster, yet compelling user experience? I am JS developer but can code Java also

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for compelling user experience - you'll want to go native.
If you already have a native iOS, and assuming you are not seeking to create your app for another platform, I would defiantly go on Native Android.

Comment: I would agree, any app I use that is clearly an iOS port never feels quite right and differentiates itself badly. They tend (but not always) to be slower, and the buttons are not where an Android user would expect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are conscious to user experience and app performance then you should go for native development for Android instead of trying `PhoneGap`